# The dual of continuous functions vanishing at infinity continuous and fuctions with support compact

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $C_{b}$(X) the set of all continuous functions with support compact and $C_{0}(X)$ the set of all functions with compact support. The dual of $C_{b}$(X) is the dual of $C_{0}(X)$?

Comment: Are you sure about your spaces? What locally convex topology do you consider on the space of *all functions with compact support*? Note, that such functions need not be bounded.

Answer (score 0):

The dual of any normed space agrees with the dual of its completion.

Concretely, you don't get new bounded linear functionals by completing your spaces. This is due to the fact that a bounded linear functional on a normed space $X$ extends uniquely to the completion $\overline X$. Indeed, if $f:X\to\mathbb C$ is linear and bounded, and $x_n\to x$, then
$$
|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|=|f(x_n-x_m)|\leq\|f\|\,\|x_n-x_m\|. 
$$
Since $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, so is the number sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$. So there exists a limit $\tilde f(x)=\lim_nf(x_n)$. One then checks that this limit is unique, which makes $\tilde f$ linear, and it is also easy to check that $\tilde f$ is bounded, with $\|\tilde f\|=\|f\|$, and that $\tilde f=f$ on $X$.